# key and value array access in php

Tags: php, arrays, key

I am calling a function like:

```
get(array('id_person' => $person, 'ot' => $ot  ));
```

In function How can I access the key and value as they are variable?

```
function get($where=array()) {

  echo where[0];
  echo where[1];
}
```

How to extract `'id_person' => $person, 'ot' => $ot`  without using **foreach** as I know how many key-values pairs I have inside function?

Comment: You need to elaborate on your usage and input variance. If you want to turn the array into an indexed version, use `array_values()` and then `$where[0]` etc. (= generally not advisable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them via `$where['id_person']` / `$where['ot']` if you know that they will always have these keys.

If you want to access the first and second element, you can do it like this

```
reset($where)
$first = current($where);
$second = next($where);
```

Comment: so `$where['id_person'] , where[0],  $where['ot'], where[1]` Is it correct

Comment: You always pass arrays that have the keys `id_person` and `ot`? Then you can do it this way

Comment: @cMinor - Your array is not numerically indexed, so you can't do `$where[0]`. You can only do `$where['id_person']` to get the first element in the array.

Comment: In php array is actually a dictionary. If you don't specify names like ``id_person`` and ``ot``, you can access things using the standard zero-based indexing, that's the default. But using key-value pairs is easier to understand in most cases.

Comment: so I understand to get value of 'id_person' I do $where['id_person'], but to know the string it self 'id_person'?

Comment: If you don't know the name of the key you can either use the method I edited in or you have to use `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

Couple ways. If you know what keys to expect, you can directly address `$where['id_person'];` Or you can extract them as local variables:

```
function get($where=array()) {
   extract($where);
   echo $id_person;
}
```

If you don't know what to expect, just loop through them:

```
foreach($where AS $key => $value) {
    echo "I found $key which is $value!";
}
```

Comment: If all of them can be variables, How would I access them, Is a foreach loop the only way out?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If they are 'variable' in that you don't know what keys will be passed in, foreach is the best way to find out.

Comment: If you want to avoid foreach() so that you can restrict how _many_ keys are allowed, just check that first. if(count($where) > 4) return "too many"; I still think you'll find foreach() the best way to figure out _what_ keys you received.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `$where['id_person']` and `$where['ot']` like you do in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about keys and want to use array as ordered array you can shift it.

```
function get($where=array()) {
$value1 = array_shift($where);
$value2 = array_shift($where);
}
```